# How to validate an XML file using Java 11 with an XSD having an import?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xsd, xsd-validation

I have a Java 11 application with Spring Boot 2.7. I need to validate XML files using XSD files. These XSD files contain imports like <xs:import schemaLocation="core-schema.xsd">, and the core-schema.xsd file is located alongside the XSD files that import it. My application is deployed as a JAR file in a container, and the XSD files are in the "resources" directory. This means I can't access them directly in my code without using an InputStream.

For validation, I'm using the following code:

```
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
final Schema schema = sf.newSchema(monXSDFile);
final Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

final StringReader reader = new StringReader(content);
validator.validate(new StreamSource(reader));
```

Now, I'm trying to use the InputStream of my XSD file in the sf.newSchema() method while still allowing access to the "core-schema.xsd" file that's imported.

I've tried using the following code:

```
final Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new Source[] {
    new StreamSource(xsdFile),
    new StreamSource(coreSchemaFile)
});
```

However, this didn't work as expected. How can I modify my approach to achieve this goal?
thanks

Comment: It sounds as if you need/want to set up https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#setResourceResolver(org.w3c.dom.ls.LSResourceResolver) to handle imports/includes. How that looks exactly in the context of Spring app I don't know but there are XML resolver libraries like https://github.com/xmlresolver that implement LSResourceResolver so using them might suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate an XML against XSD in two ways:

1. With jaxb maven plugin. Take a look here: https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/xsd-schema-validation/
2. With javax.xml.validation.Validator: Take a look here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-validate-xml-against-xsd-in-java

I prefer to work with jaxb maven plugin.